# How to accept git push to any repo path even if it doesn't exist on my server?

Tags: git, git-server

I'm trying to build an easy way for me to create & push repositories to my own server. Currently, I have to create a `--bare` repository on my server first before I can push to it.

However, I'd like to be able to dod something like this

```
git remote add origin https://user@mygitserver.com/user/new-repo.git
git push -u origin master
```

and then on the server, if `new-repo.git` doesn't exist under `user` on my server, it'll create it and continues to receive objects normally.

So, how can that be achieved on the git server?

Comment: what's kind of git-server you are using?

Comment: Well if you're using gitlab, try this https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html#push-to-create-a-new-project

Comment: @Kevin just ubuntu + git library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using gitlab as git-server, try this:

> **Push to create a new project**
>
> *Introduced in GitLab 10.5.*
>
> When you create a new repository locally, instead of going to GitLab to manually create a new project and then clone the repo locally, you can directly push it to GitLab to create the new project, all without leaving your terminal. If you have access rights to the associated namespace, GitLab will automatically create a new project under that GitLab namespace with its visibility set to Private by default (you can later change it in the project’s settings).
>
> This can be done by using either SSH or HTTPS:

```
## Git push using SSH
git push --set-upstream git@gitlab.example.com:namespace/nonexistent-project.git master

## Git push using HTTPS
git push --set-upstream https://gitlab.example.com/namespace/nonexistent-project.git master
```

If you are not using gitlab, I suggest you give it try.

You can deploy a `gitlab-ce` docker container on your ubuntu, it's pretty easy.

PS: I think gitlab do the automatic repo creating by hacking the ssh. So you can do this by just combine:
`git clone --bare my_project my_project.git`
`cp -Rf my_project/.git my_project.git` and `scp -r my_project.git user@git.example.com:/srv/git`. You can refer to the official [doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server) for more.

Comment: +1 I didn't know that was possible on GitLab, thanks. However, I'm looking for a way to do that on my own server (Ubuntu + git library).

Comment: Maybe you can deploy a `gitlab-ce`  docker container on your ubuntu, it's pretty easy.  I think gitlab do the automatic repo creating by hacking the ssh. So you can do this by just combine `git clone --bare my_project my_project.git`,  `cp -Rf my_project/.git my_project.git` and `scp -r my_project.git user@git.example.com:/srv/git`. You can refer to the [official doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server) for more.

Comment: Your last comment is great! Can you add it to your answer so I could mark it as the accepted answer?